# удаление случайных частей из списка

Tags: python

Интересует не сама реализация, а как из random.randint преобразовать число в элемент из списка. Например:

```py
one = random.randint(0,5)
print("пропала:"+str(one))
```

как сделать так, чтобы вывелось не число, а то, что под этим номером в списке?
если что-то не понятно, могу пояснить глубже. если не понятно, не осуждайте сильно, это мой первый вопрос

Comment: `list[one]` где list - ваш список

Comment: благодарю,здорово,что меня поняли сразу)))

Comment: благодарю всех!

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы узнать под каким номером число, нужно написать метод `index`. Лично я решил твой вопрос так:

```py
import random

one = random.randint(0,5)
print(one)
number=[]
number.append(one)

print("пропала:"+str(number.index(one)))
```

Ну или же, если ты хочешь удалить рандомное число в списке, то нужно использовать метод `pop`. У меня получилось сделать так:

```py
import random

number = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print("было:"+str(number))

one = random.randint(0,5)
number.pop(one)
print("стало:"+str(number))

print("пропала:"+str(one+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, необходимо вывести удалённый элемент списка вместо индекса.
Для этого можно использовать списочный метод `.pop()`. В качестве необязательного аргумента он принимает индекс, под которым располагается элемент, который нужно удалить. Этот метод возвращает удалённый элемент.
Таким образом, мы можем сгенерировать случайное число с помощью модуля `random` и передать его в качестве аргумента методу `.pop()`.
Исходный код будет выглядеть так:

```
from random import randint

my_list = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
random_index = randint(0, len(my_list))
deleted_item = my_list.pop(random_index)

print(f"Удалённый элемент: {deleted_item}")
```